# Преобразование sql-запроса в Laravel 5.3 Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

У меня запрос sql выглядит так

```
SELECT f.id as film,s.id as sid,f.name,f.description,f.avatar, count(s.id) as sc,count(t.id) as busy from films as f LEFT JOIN sessions as s on f.id = s.f_id  LEFT join tickets as t on s.id=t.s_id
```

GROUP BY sid HAVING sid IS NOT NULL

Мне нужно преобразовать его в Laravel 5.3 Eloquent

Comment: что именно вызвало у Вас затруднение?

Comment: просто не получается преобразовать на Laravel ,если можете помогите решать проблему